# Problema com navegadores

Tags: javascript, html, css, navegador-de-internet

Sou novo com desenvolvimento web e estou com um problema que acredito ser mais básico, porém esta me causando problemas. Quando eu altero meu CSS , JS ou HTML e atualizo a página no Chrome para analisar o site e ver como ficou, o site continua com a formatação antiga. Isso ocorre algumas vezes, não é sempre. Porém quando acontece me atrasa muito.

Já tentei esvaziar o cache do navegador, mas não resolve. Atualizei várias vezes a página e salvei os arquivos no local certo. Mas sempre quando inspeciono os elementos, difere do que editei nos meus arquivos.

Como resolver esse problema e como faço pra otimizar minha produtividade e evitar esses tipos de problemas?

Comment: Não sou expert com isso, mas é possível parar essa espécie de cache através do servidor, por exemplo: com PHP. Se n me engano o .htaccess também permite parar os caches. Se o arquivo já tem cache, aí vai ser melhor mudar o local do site e desativar os caches. Se você está fazendo esses testes sem servidor vai ser melhor começar usando um servidor local.

Comment: Cltr+f5, funciona aqui....

Answer (score 5):

Pressione CTRL+Shift+I para inspecionar o elemento da página, vá na aba Network e marque o checkbox Disable cache, como mostra a imagem abaixo.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sempre que o seu inspecionar elemento estiver aberto o cache não será guardado no navegador, é o que eu uso para desenvolver e funciona bem.

Answer (score 0):

Alem disabilitar o cache do browser como na resposta anterior, deixe a janela do inspetor/inspector aberta(precisa estar aberta), clique e segure o botao de reload do lado da barra de endereco, e vc vera que algumas outras opcoes de reload irao aparecer...

eu utilizo sempre o hard reload, pois possui tecla de atalho, mas vc pode utilizar a ultima opcao que ira fazer o hard reload e limpar o cache.

A fim de agilizar um pouco as coisas, vc pode tentar utilizar algumas dessas ferramentas: gruntjs, gulpjs, webpack, jest ou npm(scripting) ou algum outro "http-server" em conjunto com algum task runner(citados anteriormente).